# ASP.NET MVC login stopped working with a #_=_ callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-login

I am running a ASP.NET site that has Google and Facebook login using ASP.NET Identity OAuth login. I am on version 4.2.2 of the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` plugin. I am now experiencing that Facebook login do not login anymore and the redirect is to `accounts/Login#_=_`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Show your source code, and your OAuth2 provider configuration, and even configuration in Google, Facebook apps (callback URIs).